# Extend ReactNative's platform specific extensions?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack

Is it possible to hook into React-Native's platform specific extensions to use custom ones?

In the same way you can diverge `.ios.js` and `.android.js`, is there a way to define custom extensions `.xyz.js`. (An equivalent to webpack's [resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions))

Answer (score 2):

You can override the original bundler configuration in `rn-cli.config.js` in the project root like this:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('metro-config')

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {
      sourceExt
    }
  } = await getDefaultConfig()

  return {
    resolver: {
      sourceExts: ['xyz.js', ...sourceExts]
    }
  }
})()
```

The [bundler documentation](https://facebook.github.io/metro/docs/en/configuration#resolver-options) suggests to use the `platforms` property instead of `sourceExt`, but unfortunately, I'm having no luck with that one yet (most probably because the actual target platform still will be `ios` or `android, so RN will use that one instead of ours).

`sourceExts` extends not the platform list itself, but the extension list, which is something like `['js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx']` by default. If we expand it like `['xyz.js', 'js', 'json', 'ts', 'tsx']`, RN will pick `*.xyz.js`, if exists, first.